# What is the 'Groups' in the Case Related List?

Tags: case

I just noticed that in the Case related list, there is a section called 'Groups'.
It looks like a standard object, however I do not know how to use it and where it comes from.

This 'Groups' is also not listed in the help.

[Case Feed and Related Lists](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=case_interaction_related_lists.htm&language=en_US)

[image]

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on it :(

Answer (score 2):

This case has been shared with groups.  For example, if you mention @experts on the case feed, the experts group would be in that related list.  And if you went to the group, you'd see all the records associated with that group.

This related list can be on lots of objects now.

Comment: Hi Share, thanks a lot for your feedback. I have tried this way, it does not work.  Have I missed something here. I have @mention some Chatter groups in the Feed on this Case record.

Comment: you might want to check that your object CAN be added to groups.  http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_chatter_groups_custom_object_add_flag.htm.  you can also add it from the chatter group by clicking Add Record from the publisher: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=collab_group_records_add_follow.htm&siteLang=en_US

Comment: Thanks a for your info. I can confirm this function now.         When you create a record from a Chatter Group with Global Action, this record will be showed up in the Group Records part in this Chatter group. Also, if you open the detail page of this record, then the Chatter group info. will be showed up in the related list Groups in this record.   I guess there can only be one Group in this related list.  Anyway, thanks a lot.